# How to dispatch to generic handler from a non-generic method?

Tags: c#, reflection, dependency-injection

I have a method that needs a rework, specifically I need to remove the generic parameter in the signature. The method receives a single parameter, which always implements a specific interface.

This is the method:

```cs
public void SendCommand<T>(T command) where T : ICommand
{   
    using (var scope = services.CreateScope())
    {
        var commandType = command.GetType();
        var handlerType = typeof(ICommandHandler<>).MakeGenericType(commandType);

        var service = scope.ServiceProvider.GetService(handlerType);
        (service as ICommandHandler<T>).Handle(command);
    }
}
```

The sticking point is the `(service as ICommandHandler<T>).Handle(command)`, line, which receives a type parameter of an object that implements `ICommand`. Depending on the parameter actual type, the service retrieved is different.

Is there any way to remove the generic parameter, and use the actual type of the parameter as the generic parameter of the `ICommandHandler<T>` line?

EDIT:

This rework does the trick, but it exposes a pretty weird, perhaps buggy, behavior.

```cs
public void SendCommand(ICommand command)
{   
    using (var scope = services.CreateScope())
    {
        var commandType = command.GetType();
        var handlerType = typeof(ICommandHandler<>).MakeGenericType(commandType);

        dynamic cmd = command;
        dynamic service = scope.ServiceProvider.GetService(handlerType);

        var method = handlerType.GetMethods().Single(s => s.Name == "Handle");
        method.Invoke(service, new[] { command });

        service.Handle(cmd);
    }
}
```

Extracting the `Handle` method from the service object and invoking it manually does the trick. But using the `service.Handle(cmd)` method call throws an exception (object does not have a definition for `Handle`).

This is weird as hell, because extracting the method *does* work.

Anyone can shed light on this weirdness?

Comment: Why do you want to remove that generic parameter? Have you tried using just  `SendCommand(ICommand command)`?

Comment: I imagine this method is an implementation of an interface.  If so, you can't modify the method signature unless you also modify that interface.

Comment: Camilo, I did try SendCommand(ICommand command), The method does not work in that case, because ICommandHandler<T> requires a type. Also,  ICommand is an empty interface meant for POCO classes that just serves as a "tag" of sorts. Amy, the method is not an interface implementation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few options here:

First of all, if keeping the generic type argument is an option, you can reduce the method's complexity to the following:

```cs
public void SendCommand<T>(T command) where T : ICommand
{   
    using (var scope = services.CreateScope())
    {
        var handler = scope.ServiceProvider
            .GetRequiredService<ICommandHandler<T>>();
        handler.Handle(command);
    }
}
```

This is, of course, not what your question is about. Removing the generic type argument allows a more dynamic way of dispatching commands, which is useful when command types are not known at compile time. In that case you can use dynamic typing, as follows:

```cs
public void SendCommand(ICommand command)
{   
    using (var scope = services.CreateScope())
    {
        var commandType = command.GetType();
        var handlerType =
            typeof(ICommandHandler<>).MakeGenericType(commandType);

        dynamic handler = scope.ServiceProvider
            .GetRequiredService(handlerType);
        handler.Handle((dynamic)command);
    }
}
```

Notice two things here:

1. The resolved handler is stored in a `dynamic` variable. Its `Handle` method is, therefore, a dynamic invocation where `Handle` is resolved at runtime.
2. Since `ICommandHandler<{commandType}>` does not contain a `Handle(ICommand)` method, the `command` argument needs to be cast to a `dynamic`. This instructs the C# binding that it should look for *any* method named `Handle` method with one single argument that matches the supplied runtime type of `command`.

This option works pretty well, but there are two downsides to this 'dynamic' approach:

1. The lack of compile-time support will let any refactoring to the `ICommandHandler<T>` interface get unnoticed. This is probably not a huge problem, as it can easily be unit tested.
2. Any decorator that gets applied to any `ICommandHandler<T>` implementation needs to ensure that it is defined as a public class. The dynamic invocation of the `Handle` method will (weirdly) fail when the class is internal, as the C# binder won't spot that the `Handle` method of the `ICommandHandler<T>` interface is publicly accessible.

So instead of using dynamic, you can also use good old generics, similar to your approach:

```cs
public void SendCommand(ICommand command)
{   
    using (var scope = services.CreateScope())
    {
        var commandType = command.GetType();
        var handlerType =
            typeof(ICommandHandler<>).MakeGenericType(commandType);

        object handler = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService(handlerType);

        var handleMethod = handlerType.GetMethods()
            .Single(s => s.Name == nameof(ICommandHandler<ICommand>.Handle));

        handleMethod.Invoke(handler, new[] { command });
    }
}
```

This prevents the problems with the previous approach, as this will surfive refactoring of the command handler interface, and it can invoke the `Handle` method even if the handler is internal.

On the other hand, it does introduce a new problem. In case a handler throws an exception, the call to `MethodBase.Invoke` will cause that exception to be wrapped in an `InvocationException`. This can cause trouble up the call stack, when the consuming layer catches certain exceptions. In that case the exception should first be unwrapped, which means `SendCommand` is leaking implementation details to its consumers.

There are several ways to fix this, for instance:

```cs
public void SendCommand(ICommand command)
{   
    using (var scope = services.CreateScope())
    {
        var commandType = command.GetType();
        var handlerType =
            typeof(ICommandHandler<>).MakeGenericType(commandType);

        object handler = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService(handlerType);

        var handleMethod = handlerType.GetMethods()
            .Single(s => s.Name == nameof(ICommandHandler<ICommand>.Handle));

        try
        {        
            handleMethod.Invoke(handler, new[] { command });
        }
        catch (InvocationException ex)
        {
            throw ex.InnerException;
        }
    }
}
```

Downside of this approach, however, is that you lose the stack trace of the original exception, as this exception is rethrown (which is typically not a good idea). So instead, you can do the following:

```cs
public void SendCommand(ICommand command)
{   
    using (var scope = services.CreateScope())
    {
        var commandType = command.GetType();
        var handlerType =
            typeof(ICommandHandler<>).MakeGenericType(commandType);

        object handler = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService(handlerType);

        var handleMethod = handlerType.GetMethods()
            .Single(s => s.Name == nameof(ICommandHandler<ICommand>.Handle));

        try
        {        
            handleMethod.Invoke(handler, new[] { command });
        }
        catch (InvocationException ex)
        {
            ExceptionDispatchInfo.Capture(ex.InnerException).Throw();
        }
    }
}
```

This makes use of .NET 4.5's `ExceptionDispatchInfo` which is also available under .NET Core 1.0 and up and .NET Standard 1.0.

As a last option, you can also, instead of resolving `ICommandHandler<T>`, resolve a wrapper type that implements a non-generic interface. This makes the code types safe, but does force you to register the extra generic wrapper type. This goes as follows:

```cs
public void SendCommand(ICommand command)
{   
    using (var scope = services.CreateScope())
    {
        var commandType = command.GetType();
        var wrapperType =
            typeof(CommandHandlerWrapper<>).MakeGenericType(commandType);

        var wrapper = (ICommandHandlerWrapper)scope.ServiceProvider
            .GetRequiredService(wrapperType);

        wrapper.Handle(command);
    }
}

public interface ICommandHandlerWrapper
{
    void Handle(ICommand command);
}

public class CommandHandlerWrapper<T> : ICommandHandlerWrapper
    where T : ICommand
{
    private readonly ICommandHandler<T> handler;
    public CommandHandlerWrapper(ICommandHandler<T> handler) =>
        this.handler = handler;

    public Handle(ICommand command) => this.handler.Handle((T)command);
}

// Extra registration
services.AddTransient(typeof(CommandHandlerWrapper<>));
```

Comment: Very Informative post, thank you! Now, here's the thing: your first proposed solution (using dynamics) fails on my end, in fact is one of the failed solutions I attempted before posting in StackOverflow. Somehow, the binder fails to recognize that the object in question contains a Handle method. The watches recognize the object as being of the correct type (AddUserCommandHandler), but somehow, the method call throws an exception when invoked (which is why I had to go with extracting the method and invoking it manually)

Comment: Update, I found the reason the dynamic invocation fails. The Command and the CommandHandler classes were defined as private. Changing them to public does the trick. (defining them as internal still throws the exception)

Comment: @JorgeLuisRodriguezPerez this is the second downside I noted for the dynamic approach.